# Making random bits stored in a boolean array

Tags: java, arrays, random, boolean, bit

I'm looking for a way to store random sets of bits into an array. The code below isn't complete but I just want help understanding how to randomize a set of bits.

```
public static boolean[] makeRandomBits(int size) {
    BitSet[] bitArray = new BitSet[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        bitArray[i].set(/*Right here is where my confusion is*/);
    }

    /*other stuff below*/
}
```

I'm looking for the output to be something along the lines of: 01101001

Answer (score 0):

```
Random random = new Random();
boolean[] arr = new boolean[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
   arr[i] = random.nextBoolean();
}
return arr;
```

Comment: If I looking for the code to return a value like 01101001 or 11010101, would that be possible with this method? Sorry I don't think I made that clear in my original question.

Comment: Well... that's even easier. `(new Integer(random.nextInt(someMax))).toBinaryString()`

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you. Would the variable someMax in this instance be the amount of bits, i.e. if someMax was 7 it would create random bits from 11111111 to 00000000?

Comment: In this instance, someMax would be 2^7

Answer (score 0):

The class `java.math.BigInteger` provides a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28int,%20java.util.Random%29) that creates a random `BigInteger` of a given `bitLenght` that you can manipulate at bit level

```
Random r = new Random();
int numBits = 32;

BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(numBits,r);
```

If you need it to be a `BitSet`:

```
BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(bi.toByteArray());
```

For further information look at the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) javadocs.